# DynamicJasper: How to set style for globalFooterVariable?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Here is my code which provides **sum of columns** in **footer**.

```
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(totalAmount, DJCalculation.SUM);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(basicAmount, DJCalculation.SUM);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(cgstColumn, DJCalculation.SUM);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(sgstColumn, DJCalculation.SUM);
```

But i don't know how to **add styles** to these footer variables. **Also is it possible to resize fonts of entire report?**

Comment: The answer on your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49623525/876298) contains all you need

Answer (score 0):

Add styles in footer variables

```
Style style = new StyleBuilder(false).setFont(Font.ARIAL_SMALL)
         .setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT).setBorderBottom(Border.THIN())
         .setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE)
         .setPadding(new Integer(0))
         .setStretchWithOverflow(false)
         .build();

drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(totalAmount, DJCalculation.SUM, style);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(basicAmount, DJCalculation.SUM, style);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(cgstColumn, DJCalculation.SUM, style);
drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(sgstColumn, DJCalculation.SUM, style);
```

Also use style to resize fonts.

```
Style style = new StyleBuilder(false).setFont(new Font(18, Font.ARIAL_SMALL, true)).build();
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I got it. But i cannot change the font size of data in each column. I tried your method and it looks like it only changes font size of title, subtitle, and Column title but not the data in the column. Is i t possible to change font size of data in the column?

Comment: use `setStyle(StyleBuilder style)` sets the column value style